# Cannot get the text from the edit text widget (android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have no clue what I am doing wrong but when I print the text from the edit text (using `getText().toString()`), in the logcat it is always an empty string. I am wondering if it has to do with that it is being done inside the `onClick`function for the continue button. I'm putting the whole `onCreate` function because the code inside the `onClick` function seems to match exactly what countless tutorials have shown.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

  Button   add_test    = new Button(this);
  Button   delete_test = new Button(this);
  Button[] barray      = new Button[100];
  int      trans_grey  = Color.parseColor("#40000000");
  final String[] test_types  = new String[] {"Choose...","Terms", "Multiple choice", "Custom"};
  final ArrayAdapter<String> type_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item,test_types);

  // Preliminary operations and display opening layouts
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
  LinearLayout  scroll_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_layout);
  LayoutParams  scroll_params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


  // Add the add a dynamic button
  for (int index = 0; index <= 4; index++)
  {
      barray[index] = new Button(this);
      barray[index].setBackgroundColor(trans_grey);
      barray[index].setText("Array buttons");
      barray[index].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCffffff"));
      scroll_layout.addView(barray[index], scroll_params);
  }


  add_test.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCffffff"));
  add_test.setBackgroundColor(trans_grey);
  add_test.setText("Add a Test");
  scroll_layout.addView(add_test, scroll_params);
  add_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {@Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {

         AlertDialog.Builder add_test_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);
         final View add_test_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_test_menu, null);
         Spinner  type_spinner   = (Spinner)  add_test_view.findViewById(R.id.type);
         add_test_builder.setView(add_test_view);
         final Button continue_button = (Button) add_test_view.findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
         AlertDialog dialog = add_test_builder.create();
         dialog.show();
         dialog.getWindow().setLayout(950,900);

         type_spinner.setAdapter(type_adapter);
         continue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                View add_test_view = getLayoutInflater().
                       inflate(R.layout.add_test_menu, null);
                       // The view of the test attribute dialog
                EditText test_title     = (EditText) add_test_view.
                                       findViewById(R.id.testTitle);
                       // Test title widget to hold title of test
                String   user_title     = test_title.getText().toString();
                 Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + user_title);

             }
         });
         return;
      }
     });

  // Add the delete a test button
  delete_test.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCffffff"));
  delete_test.setBackgroundColor(trans_grey);
  delete_test.setText("Delete a Test");
  scroll_layout.addView(delete_test, scroll_params);


  return;
  }

}
```

Layout:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/testTitle"
android:maxLines="1"
android:lines="1"
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:background="#00000000"
android:hint="Test Title"/>
```

Comment: Your EditText is empty

Comment: Why are you inflating add_test_menu xml again inside onclick method of continue button.. may be this is what's causing the problem.. use the one declared above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inflate the view yiu are assigning to dialog multiple times as you are creating multiple instances of it you are writing to one view but trying to fetch the data from another....Try doing it like this...

AlertDialog.Builder add_test_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);

```
final View add_test_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_test_menu, null); 

final EditText test_title = (EditText) add_test_view. findViewById(R.id.testTitle);

 continue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

@Override public void onClick(View v) {
   String user_title = test_title.getText().toString();
 Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + user_title); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you may call editText string outside of Click method like above

```
    final EditText test_title;

    continue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
            View add_test_view = getLayoutInflater().
                   inflate(R.layout.add_test_menu, null);
                   // The view of the test attribute dialog
            EditText test_title     = (EditText) add_test_view.
                                   findViewById(R.id.testTitle);
                   // Test title widget to hold title of test



         }
     });

     String   user_title     = test_title.getText().toString();
      Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + user_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define EditText before and outside of your onlick method.  Or get string after your onlick method.